# Calculate difference from json noted date and now angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to save dates (of the last checkup) in an json file and calculate the time between now, so i can show the users when they need a new checkup. (this is yearly)

I tried something really easy but it doesn't seem to work

```
      var currentdate = $scope.user.currentdate;
      var checked = $scope.user.checked;
      var today = new Date();
      var milliseconds_passed  = Date.now() - $scope.user.checked;
      var milliseconds_per_day = 1000*60*60*24;

      // days since last checkup
      var days_passed = Math.floor(milliseconds_passed / milliseconds_per_day);

      // calculate date
      var now = new Date();
      var date_in_milli = now.setDate(now.getDate() - days_passed);

      // not sure why you need to do this because this is effectively the same date as $scope.checked
      $scope.user.currentdate = date_in_milli;

      console.log(checked);
      console.log(today);
      console.log($scope.currentdate);
```

my json file

```
{
     "id": "11",
     "name": "John Doe",
     "checked": "2015-09-21T20:51:40.946Z",
     "klantnummer": "12341234616"
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what trick I need to use to get the data calculated it and then show the user what he needs?

console log

```
2015-09-21T20:51:40.946Z
Mon Sep 21 2015 23:40:19 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
2015-09-21T20:51:40.946Z
undefined
```

Comment: dates are not part of angular specifically  and it is really easy to research this. You are expected to at least try searching yourself

Comment: i could not find any specific information in this, thats why i asked. and i want to use scopes (if i can) to do this

Comment: google `javascript compare dates` or `javascript  date difference` will keep you plenty busy with results

Comment: i will try that in the meantime, i just think i need some help with changing scopes to variables and storing the info back in too. thanks for the help tho

Comment: you might want to loop over all the data, do the calculations and add them as a property to each object. Or create a filter so they only show up in the view. There are definitely different ways to approach it, depending on if adding a property is a problem or not for saving etc

Comment: could you help me with this instead of saying my question is wrong and disliking my post? --edit-- or help me improving my question

Comment: the thing is you get a lot more help when you do the obvious simple research. The actual calculation is easy to find how. That said...of the 2 choices I gave for managing the result which is what you would prefer to do?

Comment: you said i should use javascript so i tried to change my scopes to variables, after this the actual date gets shown. it doesnt calculates the time in between tho, var currentdate = $scope.currentdate;
        var checked = $scope.checked;

        currentdate = Date(); - checked;

        $scope.currentdate = currentdate;
        $scope.checked = checked;
        console.log(currentdate);

Comment: `Date()` is an object ... and is part of javascript. There are lots and lots of ways to use that date object ... that's why the suggested research. You can't subtract a string from an object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: After my research i found out its hard to find people explaining this based on json files. but oh well, with this discussion i feel like i'm progressing to my goal after all. so you think if i use another way to get the date property (or store it in a variable) it could work?

Comment: it isn't json when you have it in your script as an array...it's then an array of objects and you need to interact wth each object to do the calcs. You can either loop over the whole array and do each one and store back to that object instance...or just do the calculation in the view

Comment: ahh yeah i see, sorry i'm very used to angular but javascript kinda scares me haha. already a step closer, i only need it to subtract the checked date now. doesn't seems the right format tho ...

Comment: that format is great... `Date.now() -  (+new Date(item.checked))` will get diff but that is in milliseconds .... and angular is javascript , it's just a framework that is built on the language

Comment: i feel quite stupid but i cant get that to work. it gives an unexpected identifier error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $scope.checked is in milliseconds. You can do this:

```
var milliseconds_passed  = Date.now() - $scope.checked;
var milliseconds_per_day = 1000*60*60*24;

// days since last checkup
var days_passed = Math.floor(milliseconds_passed / milliseconds_per_day);

// calculate date
var now = new Date();
var date_in_milli = now.setDate(now.getDate() - days_passed);

// not sure why you need to do this because this is effectively the same date as $scope.checked
$scope.currentdate = date_in_milli;
```

Comment: Sounds like an awesome solution! one problem tho, my console logs this `TypeError: now.getDate is not a function`

Comment: Fixed @JFolkertsma. I would suggest trying to learn more about javascript as well. Learn what the console log is trying to tell you.

Comment: oh im close! my console logs everything besides the actual outcome
--edit-- i just added it to my original post

Comment: what is your angularJs code look like? Try something like this to display a date : http://www.bootply.com/NmjlL7ymYa

Comment: I'm using an router to put each json entry in a separate page, id based. in this template file i got ng-show="user"  and every other bit of json information i'm using uses has a prefix of {{ user.bitofjasondata }}

not sure if im supposed to put a link here? but here it is http://d8e8200f.ngrok.io/#/app/users/11

Comment: Sorry, I don't think i can help you further. you need to learn the basics of JS and AngularJS. Go through some tutorials for both those subjects. Good luck.

Comment: I will haha, and wil accept your post as it helped me alot! thanks!

Comment: what did you write to output the date part on your template? Did you look at my link on how to output the date? http://www.bootply.com/NmjlL7ymYa Please confirm

Comment: {{ user.currentdate }}, should work because my checked value gets logged with this too

Comment: Within your javascript, do a console.log after you have set a value to it: console.log($scope.currentdate); Does it print out a value?

Comment: undefined and when im using $scope.user.currentdate it says Nan

Comment: when using this right before he scopes $scope.user.currentdate = 10; it just prints out 10, so thats good